# Regex to check for valid URL in Firebase Security Rule

Tags: regex, security, firebase, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement a firebase security rule to check if it is a valid url by using regex. Here is some sample of the url :

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/andTheRestIsJustThePartAfterIUploadedIntoFirebaseStorage
```

I used this regex to check:

```
"imageURL": {
      ".validate": "newData.val().matches(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/)"
 }
```

However, I'm getting error at `Line 26: Invalid escape: '\+'.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not necessary to escape `+` in a [`regex class`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), instead use this:

```
[-+=&;%@.\w_]
```

I see another syntax errors in your pattern, some character should be escaped athors should not, your pattern should look like this :

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[-;:&=+\\$,\\w]+@)?‌​[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:ww‌​w.|[-;:&=+\\$,\\w]+@‌​)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:‌​\\/[%+~\\/.\\w-_]*)?‌​\\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\\w_‌​]*)#?(?:[\\w]*))?)/
```

But i'm not sure of about the logic of your pattern, i could suggest to read this for more information about [Firebase Security Rules Regular Expressions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex)

Comment: it is telling me Invalid escape: '\w'  error message now

Comment: @DeniseTan what do you mean by `\w` ?

Comment: It just tell me Error saving rules - Line 26: Invalid escape: '\w' error message

Comment: @DeniseTan can you try with double backslash please `\\w` ?

Comment: you are welcome, but you have to check the logic of your regex this is the important thing @DeniseTan

Comment: Hey so I am supposed to remove all '/' before the '+' am I right? After I do so, the same error message appear again. Do you mind to post the full regex for it?

Comment: @DeniseTan try to use this `/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[+~%\/.\\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\\w_]*)#?(?:[\\w]*))?)/`

Comment: It told me no escape character '\?' for this part: ?\??

Comment: yeap I tried it earlier on. But if I added another escape character at there, it lead to another problem at this part: {3,9}:(?:\/\/)?, right before the last '?', the error message is just simply a syntax error and nothing else which I have no idea why is it so

Comment: @DeniseTan also correct you have to escape `/` with double backslash `\\/\\/` instead, what else :)

Comment: Oh my god, now the syntax error changed to this part: (?:\/[+~%\/.\\w-_]*). I tried with (?:\/[+~%\\/.\\w-_]*) and (?:\/[+~%\/\\.\\w-_]*) but both does not work also

Comment: it is logic also you escape the slash with just one bachslash `\/` it should be `\\/`

Comment: @DeniseTan can you try with this `matches(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[-;:&=+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\\/[%+~\\/.\\w-_]*)?\\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\\w_]*)#?(?:[\\w]*))?)/)"` ?

Comment: Opps the logic went haywire. I tried to input the URL like www.google.com and the access got denied which mean the regex is not validating properly now :(

Comment: @DeniseTan i told you in top be carful of the logic, did you read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex

Comment: Ah I saw a validation for URL there. Thanks so much!